# Return value of collection.add() vs Map.put()

Tags: java, api-design

In Java, Collection.add() returns a boolean which is true if the added element wasn't present in the set whereas Map.put() returns the value that was previously associated with the key (or null if there was none).

Is there any reason that aren't implemented the same way (e.g. both returning boolean)?

Comment: There's no such method as Map.add().

Comment: @COMEFROM Sorry, my bad. I meant Map.put(). Edited the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you mean `Map.put` - because there is no `Map.add`. But even if they had the same name - these methods behave differently enough to render any attempt to unify their interface meaningless.

Look at the way [`Collection.add`'s return value's doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)) is worded:

> true if this collection changed as a result of the call

Now, the only valid reason for the collection to not change is if it's a set and the item is already in there(any other reason should throw), but that wording was chosen because it makes sense for **all** collections, without having to make special clauses for sets and not-sets.

But does it make sense for maps? Consider this:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
map.put(1, 2);
map.put(2, 2);

/*case 1*/ map.put(1, 1); // value changed - would have returned `true`
/*case 2*/ map.put(2, 2); // nothing changed - would have returned `false`
/*case 3*/ map.put(3, 3); // key-value pair added - would have returned `true`
```

Case 1 and 3 both return `true`, but they are very different - one is overriding an entry and the other adding a new one. So maybe case 1 should have returned `false`? But then it would have been the same as case 2, even though one is changing the map and the other doesn't...

So, copying `Collection.add`'s behavior to `Map.put` makes no sense. How about copying `Map.put`'s behavior to `Collection.add`? What if we had `Collection.add` return the old value?

I see several problems with that:

1. It makes the interface more complicated - now it needs to give different definitions for maps and sets, or make a more complex definition(e.g. - "if the item was not added because it was already there, return the item that was already there". Ugh...)
2. It's not very useful. You already have the item that's already in the collection - you just sent it as an argument to `add`!
3. What if we have a `TreeSet` with a custom comparator?

   ```
   TreeSet<Integer> treeSet = new TreeSet<Integer>((a, b) -> Integer.compare(a % 10, b % 10));

   treeSet.add(11);
   treeSet.add(21); // should this return `11` or `21`?
   ```

   This is not a problem with `Map`, because it's looking by the key, and is already forced to define what you get when you request for that key.
4. It forces the collection to actually retrieve the value. What if the `Collection` implementation is a bloom filter? It now has to actually look for the object instead of doing a quick hash match. What if it's a wrapper around a database table? It now has to create an object that you already have!

   Of course, `Map` would have a similar problem - but at least there the old value is important, because you don't know what it is and it's going to disappear. But with `Collection`? It's all cost and no gain...

Answer (score 2):

**Collection.add** returns whether the collection has changed or not.

**Map.put** returns the previous element for the key.

These are simply different functionality.

There is not "equivalent" method in Collection interface. However you have **[List.set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set(int,%20E))** which returns the previous element in the position. Note that a Map is not a Collection.

Answer (score 0):

Both collection designers tried to use the return value of the method to give you something useful. An add method can only tell you if the the item was already present, this is information you may want to act upon.

What can the map give you? The most information is the last value the key had, this tells you both if the item already existed and another information that only the Map data structure has - the last value.